# Excel Vlookup Across Different Sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a excel file with 2 work sheets. They look like this:

Sheet 1:

[image: sheet1]

Sheet 2:

[image: sheet2]

I want to look up the value of column A (**sheet1**) when matched with column A (**sheet 2**) copy the value of column B (**sheet 2**) to column B (**sheet 1**).

I know I have to use vlookup but I really have no idea where to start with this.

An example of the result:

[image: wanted result]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VLOOKUP works by taking a square range of data, looking at the first column of that data for a match you specify, and then returning the value of that row a given number of columns to the right. For example, in your case, it would look as follows [for B2 in sheet1, copied down]:

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,'Sheet2'!A:B, 2, FALSE)
```

This takes the value from cell A2, then looks at column A on sheet2. If it finds a match, it returns the value on the 2nd column of the table [ie: column B]. If there is no match, it will return #N/A. The FALSE means that it doesn't assume your data is sorted [if it is, you can use VLOOKUP to take a 'next best' value if there is no match.

Comment: It actually has to use `;` instead of `,`. But even then it's giving me an error  . `#NAME?`

Comment: @BramDriesen - Make sure you edit the sheet name, if yours is actually `Sheet 2`, then use that (note the space).

Comment: @BramDriesen ";" or "," is based on locale/language settings. As Bruce points out, #NAME? error indicates that you don't have a sheet named Sheet2. Fix the name to what you actually have, and it should work.